# Why do 14.04 updates of Linux 3.13.0.151 and 3.13.0.153 not boot

Tags: 14.04, boot

14.04 updates of Linux 3.13.0.151 and 3.13.0.153 just return to grub menu.
Selecting Linux 3.13.0.150 correctly boots.

Answer (score 1):

This could have any of a number of causes.

Have you checked if your disks have enough space? The auto-update feature in Ubuntu 14.04 tends fill up disks (and /boot in particular) with old kernels  behind your back if you're not careful.

```
df -h / /boot
```

And you can check for old kernels to remove using

```
dpkg -l linux-image* linux-headers*
```

Just make sure you don't remove the working one :P

If /boot has enough free space, you can update the initramfs images of the installed kernels:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

And you can also try to trigger a grub update:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Blacky. Followed your suggestions and can now boot from  3.13.0.153.
Not sure which cured problem but very grateful.

Derek Yawder